# Appending a string to all elements of cells in a column using awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following text file:

```
$ cat file.txt
# file;GYPA;Boston
Josh      81-62    20
Mike      72-27    1;42;53
Allie     71-27    24;12
```

I would like to add GYPA to every element of the third column in the following manner:

```
GYPA:20
GYPA:1;GYPA:42;GYPA:53
GYPA:24;GYPA:12
```

so far, I have

cat combine.awk

```
NR==1 {
    FS=";"; Add=$2
}

{
    FS="\t"; split($3,a,";");
    for (i in a) {
        print Add":"a[i] 
    }

}
```

the array part did not work.

Comment: (1) Changing FS in an action is too late to affect parsing of the current record (2) there is no special patttern `else` in awk; it is an ordinary variable, and since you didn't set it, it is zero and thus never 'matches' (3) that code if executed would produce a different format than you ask for

Comment: Do you **really** want to add a hard-coded GYPA or do you instead want to add whatever's in the 2nd field of the first line of the input file (which just happens to by GYPA in this example)?

Comment: Not hard coded. I am adding whatever's in the second field of `/~ #/` which is also `NR==1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's no backreference (e.g. `&`) or escape chars in the prefix string you want to add:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR==1{add=$2":"; FS=" "; next} {gsub(/(^|;)/,"&"add,$3); print $3}' file
GYPA:20
GYPA:1;GYPA:42;GYPA:53
GYPA:24;GYPA:12
```

Comment: `"&"` now that was a nugget I didn't know `awk` could behave like `sed` with... Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain what are the `"`s around the `&` for? My understanding is that `&` is either the empty string (when `^` matches the beginning of `$3`) or  `;`; `add` is the second header followed by `:`. But why those two `"`s?

Comment: The 2nd argument to `gsub()` is a string. `"&"and` is the string you get when you concatenate the string `"&"` with the value of the variable `and`. The `"`s are just string delimiters - `&` alone would be an awk language symbol while `"&"` is a string containing the character `&` which means a backreference for the entire matching string from the 1st arg in the context of the 2nd arg to gsub().

Comment: In a way `&` is not a `awk` variable, whereas `add` is, is this right?

Comment: In **every** way, `&` is not an awk variable - on it's own as `&` it's a symbol and within `"&"` its a character in a string. Yes, `add` is an awk variable.

Comment: Just a quick question, assuming that there are empty cells in $3, is there a way to use `gsub(/(^.|;)/)`? NOTE: `^.` The cells are in the following format `c.122C>T;c.131G>A`. After applying `gsub(^.|;)` I got `c"text".122C>T;"text"c.131G>A`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there. `^.` means `any character at the start of a string` - it seems unlikely you want to replace that with anything. Please ask a new question with it's own sample input/output if you'd like help.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == 1 {
    # Get the replacement string from the first line
    split($0, h, ";");
    add = h[2]
    next
}
{
    # split the last field by ';' into the array 'a'
    # n contains the number of elements in 'a'
    n=split($3,a,";");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        # print every element of a, separate by ','
        printf "%s%s:%s", (i-1)?",":"", add, a[i];
    }
    # finish the line by printing the ORS
    print ""
}
```

Comment: I was missing that printf "/n". Thanks

Comment: note that when you use `for(i in a)`, as in your question, the order of elements will be random.

Answer (score 2):

**My mistake**

The clarification (maybe obvious for someone) that `GYPA` is not to be hardcoded in the script, but has to be obtained from the first line starting with `#` came in a comment; I did not see it, hence my answer in the follwing is wrong.

**Actual (wrong) answer**

Why not `sed`?

```
< file.txt sed -n '/^#/!{s/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* */GYPA:/;s/;/;GYPA:/g;p}'
```

Well, written like this is a bit unreadable, so maybe rewritten like this is better:

```
< file.txt sed -n '  # -n inhibits the automatic printing
/^#/!{                   # only for lines starting with #
s/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* */GYPA:/ # change the first two columns, space included to GYPA:
s/;/;GYPA:/g             # add a GYPA: after each semicolon
p                        # print the resulting line
}'
```

Actually I'm maybe too much addicted to the `-n` option, and I should cure myself, as not using that (or any other option) allows you to put all in script which is automatically interpreted as a `sed` script by the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/^#/d
s/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* */GYPA:/
s/;/;GYPA:/g
```

which you can use like this:

```
< file.txt ./thefileabove
```

Comment: Note sure if you know this? http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html :)

Comment: PS: if you want to keep the filename at the beginning of the line, and the sed command at the end, just use shell input redirection: `< input_file sed 's/a/b/;...'`

Comment: Was basically about to say the same thing. `cat some_file |` is sometimes harmless, but sometimes a source of gross inefficiency (f/e, `cat hugefile.txt | tail -n 1` has to read the whole file from the beginning, whereas `tail -n 1 <hugefile.txt` can jump straight to the end; similarly, with a real file handle, `sort` can parallelize... but not when all it has is a FIFO from `cat`, which can only be read once front-to-back rather than having threads sort subsets to have the results merged).

Comment: @hek2mgl, I never use cat that way, but what is the best way to "simulate" that something is going through a pipe?

Comment: Well, memory-wise `zcat |` or `cat |` reads line by line. with `< file` it prints the entire file into memory. When the file size gets large, `cat |` helps

Comment: That's utterly untrue. `<file` does not create any temporary files at all *or* load content into memory ahead-of-time, it just opens `file` and attaches it to FD 0 so the program you're running can read from it. Maybe you're thinking about a heredoc or herestring? `<<<"$whatever"` does indeed create a temporary file, but that's an entirely different thing.

Comment: ...and `cat` doesn't operate line-by-line -- it would be less efficient if it tried to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I remember I had an issue with `awk NR==FNR` where I was feeding a huge zipped file and a second query file. `zcat |` used much less memory that <(zcat file.gz) < input -. Not sure why?

Comment: I'd have to see a reproducer to comment. If you do ask that as a question, feel free to @ me in.

Comment: @user171558 IIRC you were testing with 2 different awk scripts and that issue was caused by a bug in one of the awk scripts you were testing with, not by the way you were calling the 2 scripts. The one that was using a lot of memory was testing `a[$1]` instead of `$1 in a` and so filling the array `a[]` with the `$1` values from every line of your input file.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I had not read your second comment, which is actually really helpful!

Comment: Glad you find it useful! :)

Comment: @user171558 also wrt [a file being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011272/appending-a-string-to-all-elements-of-cells-in-a-column-using-awk-or-bash/60012134?noredirect=1#comment106134296_60011922) and remembering a previous discussion we had, I think you're confusing `< file` with `<(command)`. Try running `awk '{print FILENAME; exit}' < file` and compare to `awk '{print FILENAME; exit}' <(cat file)`

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis sed version with dynamic replacement: `< file.txt sed -r '1{s/[^;]*;([^;]*);.*/\1/;h;d};s/([^ ]*[ ]*){2}//;G;s/(^.*)\n(.*)/\2:\1\n\2/;:a;s/;(.*)\n(.*)/\x0\2:\1\n\2/;t a;s/\x0/;/g;s/(.*)(\n.*)/\1/'`

Comment: PS: As you can see, if the problem gets just slightly different, sed can become a dead end. I recommend to always use `awk` for this kind of problems, it's much more easy  to write, read and maintain.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ahahahah, obviously unreadable, but yes, I got it. Except for the body of the "while loop": what is `\x0`??? Yes, `awk` is easier to write/read/maintain, but would you really say it is as fun as `sed`? It's "just" a full-fledged programming language.

Comment: I have fun with awk, no worries :) .. `\x0` is a null byte. I've used it to temporarily replace the `;` in order to avoid an endless loop. Since it's text, it can be safely assumed that the input itself doesn't contain null bytes. But what I'm talking, just read the code! :D ...